# How do i create unittest in pyramid with mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid

I have a pyramid project that uses mongodb for storage. Now I'm trying to write a test but how do I specify connection to the mongodb?

More specifically, which database should I connect to (test?) and how do I use fixtures? In Django it creates a temporary database but how does it work in pyramid?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a database in your TestCase.setUp and delete in TestCase.tearDown

You need mongodb running because there is no mongolite3 like sqlite3 for sql

I doubt that django is able to create a temporary file to store a mongodb database. It probably just use sqlite:/// which create a database with a memory storage.

Comment: Hey, tnx for the reply. I've already managed to create a test db on the fly. :)